# R: How to improve performance of grepl in apply function within dataframe

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, lapply, grepl

I have data frame with the below cols:

```
country<- c("CA","IN","US")
text   <- c("paint red green", "painting red", "painting blue")
word   <- c("green, red, blue", "red", "red, blue")
df     <- data.frame(country, text, word)
```

For each row I want to find the words in the word column within the text in the text column and present them in a new column, so there will be shown the founded words in the text, separated by comma.
so the new column should be:

```
df$new_col   <- c("green,red","red","blue")
```

I am using these lines of code, but it take to much time to run and even collapse.

```
setDT(df)[, new_col:= paste(df$word[unlist(lapply(df$word,function(x) grepl(x, df$text,
     ignore.case = T)))], collapse = ","), by = 1:nrow(df)]
```

Is there a way to change the code so it will be more efficient?

Thank a lot!

Comment: Your reproducible example is great, but the performance of your actual use-case may depend quite a bit on the specifics of your data. For example, if the `word` column has relatively few distinct entries, you may want to apply `unique`. There may be alternative data structures to explore too -- currently your solution is good for presentation in a document but might be less useful within the analysis of a large data set.

Comment: Although it's great you have a reprex, I can't see how the `setDT...` code produces your intended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another base R solution using `mapply` + `grep` + `regmatches`, i.e.,

```
df <- within(df, newcol <- mapply(function(x,y) toString(grep(x,y,value = TRUE)), 
                                  gsub("\\W+","|",word), 
                                  regmatches(text,gregexpr("\\w+",text))))
```

such that

```
> df
  country            text             word     newcol
1      CA paint red green green, red, blue red, green
2      IN    painting red              red        red
3      US   painting blue        red, blue       blue
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
mapply(function(x,y){paste(intersect(x,y),collapse=", ")},
       strsplit(as.character(df$text),"\\, | "),
       strsplit(as.character(df$word),"\\, | "))

[1] "red, green" "red"        "blue"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>% 
   mutate(newcol = stringr::str_extract_all(text,gsub(", +","|",word)))
      country            text             word     newcol
    1      CA paint red green green, red, blue red, green
    2      IN    painting red              red        red
    3      US   painting blue        red, blue       blue
```

In this case, `newcol`  is a list. To make it a string, we can do:

```
df%>%
  mutate(newcol = text %>%
           str_extract_all(gsub(", +", "|", word)) %>%
           invoke(toString, .))
```

with data.table, you could do:

```
 df[,id := .I][,newcol := do.call(toString,str_extract_all(text,gsub(', +',"|",word))),
      by = id][, id := NULL][]
   country            text             word     newcol
1:      CA paint red green green, red, blue red, green
2:      IN    painting red              red        red
3:      US   painting blue        red, blue       blue
```

Comment: hi, thanks. but when I ran it on my dataframe I got an error:  `Error in if (missing(width) || is.null(width) || width == 0) return(string) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: @MatanRetzer Does the code work in the example you gave?

Comment: You are right, my data is a bit different from this example,mainly because it is in upper case

Comment: @ you can change all to lower cases, or use `ignore.case = TRUE`